# NDK-Build how to rebuild project?

Tags: build, cygwin, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am using a dual project structure cocos2d-x for windows and android, and using cygwin to build my project, at first it build the whole solution:

## build

$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT $*

but in posterior builds it does not build my modified files. How do I force it to rebuild the whole project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was solved by passing the clean parameter, another possible solution is to force by using the -B parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is it, but if you use Eclipse, you have to refresh your project (F5 or right-click on the project in Project Explorer and select Refresh), after ndk-build and *then* build it in Eclipse. When you build you native portion on command line, Eclipse is *not* automatically aware of file changes that were made.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that ndk-build does not build the project again. I solved it by forcing a clean on ndk-build.

Comment: Great, you should accept your own answer whenever the system allows you to do so.

Comment: done. thanks for the tip, did not know we could anwser own questions.